# EventLogQuery with xpath position function

Tags: c#, xpath, event-log

I've tried to query event logs using the `position()` function, without success.

I tried the following queries to get the first 10 event logs, but got back 0 results:

1. `*[System/Level=2 and position() <= 10]`
2. `*[System/Level=2][position() <= 10]`

Full code:

```
EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=2]");
query.session = new EventLogSession(Environment.MachineName);
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query);
for (EventRecord eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent();
    null != eventInstance;
    eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent())
{
    // Output or save your event data here.
}
```

According to the [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa385231(v=vs.85)#selection-limitations), `position()` should be supported:

> ◦ The position function, and its shorthand array reference, are
>   supported (on leaf nodes only).

What am I doing wrong?